# Audiokit Midi multiple virtual ports

Tags: swift, midi, audiokit

in my project I need to have an array virtualInputPort and a array of virtualOutputPort, searching in github I found that the framework disposes only one virtualInput and only one virtualOutput and that when I call createVirtualPorts or createVirtualOutputPort or createVirtualInputPort first of all is called destroyVirtualPorts() method or destroyVirtualInputPort() or destroyVirtualOutputPort().
How can I do?

Comment: Please reformat your question into proper sentences rather than just a stream of consciousness. I don't understand your question... "How can I do?" isn't enough to understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: You’re right sorry I’d like to know how I could solve the problem and create

Comment: More virtual ports

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  AudioKit does not yet support multiple virtual ports.  But what you are proposing sounds totally reasonable and it should be fairly easy to implement, and AudioKit is Open Source.

You can fork AudioKit and make changes to support multiple virtual ports, then submit a pull request.  I've made changes like this recently to AKMIDI and they are really nice about it.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply! I’ll try to create a subclass and after override that methods (I hope to succeed)! Thankyou again!